# Mac OS goes into Recovery mode at every update

Tags: macos, startup, software-update, big-sur

After updating my Mac to Big Sur, every single 11.x update of Mac OS (including the update to Big Sur itself, as well as the latest to 11.4) ends up with restarting my Mac to Recovery mode, that is, I am presented with the following panel:

[image: macOS Recovery]

(This is from my latest upgrade to 11.4 – I took a picture, because the usual shortcuts to take a screenshot don't work while in Recovery mode.)

I found out that I don't need to go ahead with logging in here, and I can just restart my Mac and the update will continue successfully, eventually showing the regular user login fields. Every update has been eventually successful, but I need to take this extra step of restarting in the middle of the update when I am shown the Recovery mode options, which is annoying, because it assumes a manual step for the update to finish.

After the manual restart, I still see the progress bar of the update starting from empty and progressing.

This was not happening on previous macOS versions. I am afraid that at some point the underlying issue will manifest itself and some future update will bork my computer.

Why does updating macOS Big Sur end up in Recovery mode?

EDIT: this is still an issue on MacOS 12.5.1, MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2016, Two Thunderbolt 3 ports)

Comment: The macOS Installer is the same as macOS Recovery so you may just be booting into the installer that was downloaded when you were trying to update. However, this will most likely not harm your computer. This can be normal for some users.

Comment: Does this happen when you restart your computer normally?

Comment: @EzekielElin No, only during updates.

Comment: Do you have a firmware password?

Comment: @Gilby no, I don't.

Comment: Did you make any changes to the system volume by any chance? Since macOS Big Sur, all system files are located on a Signed System Volume (SSV), which if modified without creating a snapshot and blessing the changes will cause issues every time your computer boots up/updates.